# how to return user attributes in SAML response in WSO2 identity server

Tags: attributes, wso2, response, identity, saml

I have added claims and choose enable attribute profile and include attributes in the response always, but attributes in SAML is null.

Comment: <saml2:AttributeStatement/>

Comment: Unnecessary Capitalization...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add claim mappings to the SP configration and mark the claims as required.

And currently (wso2 is 5.0.0 sp1) it works only when configured manually (through the management console), I cannot get it work through the file based configuration.

Comment: thanks for your answer!i have found the reason why it didn`t work.there is a service pack to fix it.